# Docker 1.6.2 - memory limiting per container doesn't work

Tags: docker

I have application working as set of microservicies. Each microservice is running in separate docker container. **I'm looking for method to set the maximum allowable memory, which each container can use.** For now I've 12 of them, which drains all of 16GB RAM. Sometimes this make working on console a little bit difficult, because of lags.

I'm starting containers using command like this one

`docker run -d -p 8093:8080 --env-file ./saturno-environment-files/edge-server.list --name edge-server acisa/edge-server --memory=1g`

I see in docker inspect -container- that this command is recognized properly

`root@PlatformServer:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice# docker inspect edge-server
[{
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "Args": [
        "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",
        "-Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE_ACTIVE}",
        "-jar",
        "/app.jar",
        "--memory=1g"
    ],
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "Cmd": [
            "--memory=1g"
        ],`

But unfortunately containers still fill memory up to 80~95%. In docker stats I see that memory limit is still 15.68GiB (physical RAM in server), and what makes me curious MEM USAGE is reported as 0B.

`CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O
edge-server         0.00%               0 B/15.68 GiB       0.00%               13.65 MiB/38.12 MiB`

Comment: Have you tried passing the memory allocation to docker, rather than to whatever is running inside the container? In other words, move the `--memory 1g` clause, for example, between your `-d` and `-p` flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you pass after the image name becomes the `CMD` value for your container, and when you have an entrypoint defined, the cmd becomes args at the end of the entrypoint. So with the command you provided:

- `docker run`: docker client with the run option
- `-d`: detached
- `-p 8093:8080`: expose container port 8080 to host port 8093
- `--env-file ./saturno-environment-files/edge-server.list`: use this file to pass env variables
- `--name edge-server`: name the container
- `acisa/edge-server`: first thing that isn't a flag to `docker run`, this is your image name and ends the args to `docker run`
- `--memory=1g`: cmd that is passed as arguments to the image entrypoint

To fix this, you just need to reorder the cli options:

```
docker run -d -p 8093:8080 --env-file ./saturno-environment-files/edge-server.list --name edge-server --memory=1g acisa/edge-server
```

Note that the memory quota features may also depend on a newer kernel and that your install of docker is extremely out of date.

Comment: Hello,Thank You for assistance. This was stupid mistake, but now memory limiting it is working :) Unfortunately swap not at all :( When I'm starting docker I see message like "parameter was rejected due to too old kernel". In host I've 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 so I assume I must upgrade docker itself?

Comment: A 4.x kernel is more than current enough. I would recommend upgrading the docker version before trying to debug anything else. I would get to at least a 17.03 install if you're on the community (open source) edition.